# Moscow Pay As You Go card

Tags: public-transport, russia, moscow

I am planning to visit Moscow for a week. It seems like I will be using transport a lot. I will be switching to different types of transport. (e.g. Underground then tram then bus).

Is there a card that allows for unlimited transport within a certain period without paying for multiple journeys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a card called **Troika**. It allows a reduced fare for single journeys and for 56 Rubles unlimited journeys in 90 minutes. This card can be obtained in automated ticket booths at most stations. The 50 rubles can be refunded after the card is handed in to a cashier.

Comment: Sorry for off-topic, but I wonder how you was able to find, type, and post an answer within less than 1 second after the question was asked? (Or is there a bug with times/dates on this website?)

Comment: @user77409 Anyone with at least 15 reputation can ask and answer their own question at the same time by [ticking the check box](/help/self-answer).

Comment: Is there enough English and/or Latin script used on the Moscow Metro that someone who doesn't speak Russian or read Cyrillic will be able to find the card?

Comment: @MichaelHampton On the auto machine there is a picture and it is quite basic. For the cashier you can just say it and give them the money.

Comment: Note that Troika will not work on the suburban bus lines run by Mostransavto and commuter trains ran by RZD, you will need a [Strelka](https://strelkacard.ru/) card for those (though getting suburban train tickets is easier from a ticket machine at the station anyway). Neither of these cards will work on privately run marshrutki(jitneys) which only accept cash.